# Webpack : Invalid configuration object/ Invalid Module Entry

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Unable to successfully compile webpack and generate bundle.js file. From what I understand, my src_dir and dist_dir variables are able to point to the correct paths but I still consistently receive one of two errors when trying to compile.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'.

&&

Entry Module not found:  ~full path to my index.jsx file ~

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "mypetstore",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "BoxKnight developer challenge ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -d --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ianlennymatthews/MyPetStore.git"
  },
  "author": "Ian Lenny Matthews",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ianlennymatthews/MyPetStore/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ianlennymatthews/MyPetStore#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.35.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

My webpack config file

```
var path = require('path');
var SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/src');
var DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(SRC_DIR, '/index.jsx'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Add File Structure

```
.
├── client
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── src
│       ├── components
│       │   └── AddressForm.jsx
│       └── index.jsx
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── server
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Please show your directory structure. The `webpack.config.js` you posted is probably correct, except for the path to `index.jsx`.

Comment: @laptou Just made the edit, thank you

Comment: Try changing your `AddressForm.jsx` to lowercase (remember to change it in any imports as well). It has caused problems for me in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/) implies that `context` is necessary and `entry` should be a relative path to `context`.

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
>   entry: "./home.js"
> };
> ```

Try modifying your webpack.config.js to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  context: SRC_DIR,
  entry: "./index.jsx",
  // ...
};
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! is context something new to a recent version of webpack?

Comment: @Ian I don't think so, I just think that it was always "recommended" and that "recommended" has slowly changed to "required"

Comment: Also, `context` is set to the current working directory of the process by default, so sometimes you can get away with not specifying it in your configuration ... but this is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot

Answer (score 0):

Try `path.resolve` instead of `path.join`.

```
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/client/src');
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/client/dist');
```

Then in the config.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle': `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
  },
  output: {
    path: `${DIST_DIR}`,
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately if threw me this error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/client'

```